# Hibernate - How to retrieve an image from the database?

Tags: hibernate

I somehow managed to store an image in the database, but now I want to retrieve/display the image again. I just do not know how. Basically my question is if I am missing any further method in my ImageDao or how the configuration in the jsp should look like.

There is my Image Class:

```
package de.hdu.pms.model;

import java.sql.Blob;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="tbl_image")
public class Image {
     @Id
     @GeneratedValue
     @Column(name="image_id")
      private Integer id;


        private String name;


        private String description;


        private String filename;

        @Column(name="content", columnDefinition="mediumblob")
        @Lob
        private Blob content;


        private String contentType;

        private Date created;

        public Integer getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Integer id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public String getFilename() {
            return filename;
        }

        public void setFilename(String filename) {
            this.filename = filename;
        }

        public Blob getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(Blob content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getContentType() {
            return contentType;
        }

        public void setContentType(String contentType) {
            this.contentType = contentType;
        }

        public Date getCreated() {
            return created;
        }

        public void setCreated(Date created) {
            this.created = created;
        }



}
```

ImageDao

```
package de.hdu.pms.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;



import de.hdu.pms.model.Image;


public class ImageDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {


        public void save(Image image) {
            HibernateTemplate template = getHibernateTemplate();
            template.saveOrUpdate(image);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public List<Image> list() {
           HibernateTemplate template = getHibernateTemplate();
            //evtl ersetzen durch hibernate template
           @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
           List images=template.loadAll(Image.class);
            return images;
        }

        public Image get(Integer id) {
            HibernateTemplate template = getHibernateTemplate();
            return template.get(Image.class, id);
        }



     @Transactional
     //hibernate
        public void remove(Integer id) {
          HibernateTemplate template = getHibernateTemplate();

            Image image = template.get(Image.class, id);
             template.delete(image);
        }

}
```

ImageController:

```
package de.hdu.pms.ctrl;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Hibernate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;



import de.hdu.pms.dao.CocktailDao;
import de.hdu.pms.dao.ImageDao;
import de.hdu.pms.model.Image;

@Controller
public class ImageController {

    @Autowired
    private ImageDao imageDao;

    public ImageDao getImageDao(){
        return imageDao;
    }

    public void setImageDao(ImageDao imageDao){
        this.imageDao = imageDao;
    }
    //aus dem Tutorial

     @RequestMapping("/EditImage.html")
     public String index(Map<String, Object> map) {
            try {
                map.put("image", new Image());
                map.put("imageList", imageDao.list());
            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "edit-image";
        }

        //aus dem Tutorial




     @RequestMapping(value = "/SaveImage.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public String save(
                @ModelAttribute("image") Image image,
                @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {


            System.out.println("Name:" + image.getName());
            System.out.println("Desc:" + image.getDescription());
            System.out.println("File:" + file.getName());
            System.out.println("ContentType:" + file.getContentType());

            try {
                Blob blob = Hibernate.createBlob(file.getInputStream());

                image.setFilename(file.getOriginalFilename());
                image.setContent(blob);
                image.setContentType(file.getContentType());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                imageDao.save(image);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return "redirect:/AlleImages.html";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/download/{imageId}")
        public String download(@PathVariable("imageId")
                Integer imageId, HttpServletResponse response) {

            Image img = imageDao.get(imageId);
            try {
                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=\"" +img.getFilename()+ "\"");
                OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
                response.setContentType(img.getContentType());
                IOUtils.copy(img.getContent().getBinaryStream(), out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return null;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value="/AlleImages.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public ModelAndView list(){
            ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
            mv.addObject("title", "Images");
            mv.addObject("message", "Alle gespeicherten Images");
            mv.addObject("image", imageDao.list());
            // für die jsp bedingung 
            mv.addObject("edit",true);
            mv.setViewName("list-image");
            return mv;
        }


}
```

And finally a code snippet of my jsp where I wanted to "access" the image - but I failed :

```
                                                    <h3>Image List</h3>
                                                    <c:if  test="${!empty imageList}">
                                                    <table class="data">
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <th>Description</th>
                                                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <c:forEach items="${imageList}" var="image">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td width="100px">${image.name}</td>
                                                            <td width="250px">${image.description}</td>
                                                            <td width="250px">${image.content}</td>


                                                        </tr>
                                                    </c:forEach>
```

I really would appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your understanding of how HTTP and HTML work. When a web page contains an image, the HTML doesn't containg the content of the image. All it contains is an `img` tag, with an src attribute containing the URL of this image:

```
<img src="/the/path/of/the/image.jpg"/>
```

The browser sends a first request to get the HTML page. Then it parses the HTML, sees the `img` tag, and sends a second request to the URL of the image to get its content (bytes) and display it.

Your code tries to generate an HTML page containing the blob (in fact, the result of calling toString() on the blob) directly in the page:

```
<td width="250px">${image.content}</td>
```

That is incorrect.

What you need to generate is an image tag whose src attribute contains the URL of the action which will get the image bytes from the database and send them to the browser, i.e. an `img` tag pointing to the download action:

```
<td width="250px"><img src="<c:url value='/download/${image.id}'/>"/></td>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. After your comment - and some other problems - I had to rethink my whole project again. I adjusted the jsp as you said, but the image is not displayed. I do not get an error message. It's just an "x".