# Upload image in spring mvc

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am using spring 4 and hibernate 4 to upload and retrieve image to and from database.
I have converted multipart image into byte array and stored in database.
My query is how to retrieve that image from database and display the byte array in jsp without storing it in local system.

Comment: Out of context It is better to upload the image in the `disk path`, rather using the database

Comment: I went through it, but in my case i need to store it in db, any solution?

Comment: sorry i am not familiar with hibernate . just try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567553/save-and-retrieve-image-from-database-using-spring-mvc-and-hibernate-rest-servic and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384928/hibernate-how-to-retrieve-an-image-from-the-database

Comment: NP:) try out and post here for specific problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you haven't mentioned your DB structure for storing the images, I assume that you are storing it in `blob` datatype.

**Part 1**: **ControllerClass**

After retrieving the image from the DB, you have to encode that image using `Base64.encode` and map that image to your jsp (using `java.util.map`).

```
Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
model.put("myImage", Base64.encode(MyImage)); //MyImage (datatype 'byte[]') is the image retrieved from DB
return new ModelAndView("display", model); //display is the name of jsp on which you want to display image
```

**Part 2**: **JSP**

Then display it on the `JSP` by decoding the byte array,

```
<img id="myImg" name="myImg" src="data:image/jpg;base64,<c:out value='${myImage}'/>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Literally what we are doing is

in dao method

```
public InputStream get_user_photo_by_id(int id_user) throws Exception {     
    Blob blob_photo;
    String sql = "Select b_photo_file from user_master where id_user = ?";                      
blob_photo = getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new Object[] {id_user}, Blob.class);     
    if(blob_photo!=null)
        return blob_photo.getBinaryStream();
    else
        return null;
}
```

In service method just returning inputstream to controller

In controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "admin/user/{id}/photo", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
public byte[] testphoto(@PathVariable("id") int id_sys_user, HttpSession ses) throws Exception {        
    byte[] thumb = null;
    InputStream in = UserOps.getUserPhotobyId(id_sys_user);     
    if(in!=null){
        thumb = IOUtils.toByteArray(in); 
    }
    return thumb;       
}
```

now just plug in admin/user/{id}/photo or any string you wish to use in < img src="">
as long as they match and you got your photo

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without problem. You have to set up a controller that will send the image when a browser requests it. But here, the controller does not put it in a Model to give it to a view, but directly generate the HTTP response. Then in your JSP, you simply indicates the relevant URL.

Here is a (partial) example of what it could be :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/img/{imgid}")
public void getFile(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable(value = "imgid") long imgid, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    contentType = "img/png"; //or what you need
    response.setContentType(contentType);
    // find the image bytes into into byte[] imgBytes
    response.setContentLength((int) imgBytes.length);
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    os.write(imgBytes);
}
```